# Push data from server to client via thrift

Tags: c#, client-server, thrift

In thrift c# [tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/csharp) provided on Apache's website, client has to request server to send data.

I want to send data from server to client without client asking for it. As well as client sending data to the server too.

Is it possible to do it via Thrift? If yes, then how? And if not then what else can i use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Apache Thrift for two-way communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746279/use-apache-thrift-for-two-way-communication)

Comment: @JensG Client side in my project is a web page so can't have server there. I can try long polling method but i was thinking if it is possible without client requesting for any data?

Comment: AFAIK some people have used it with web sockets. I never tried that so I can't say much about that myself.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to look into it.